# Error syncing Google Calendar, when i login with the account in the flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, cloud

I would like to implement a function for synchronizing a Google calendar in my Flutter project. I have a button with the corresponding function for this purpose. I log in there with the Google account from which the calendar should be synchronized. I also get a token. But then the following error occurs:
Error accessing Google Calendar: Access was denied (www-authenticate header was: Bearer
realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error="insufficient_scope", scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar....

The API key actually has no restrictions in Google Cloud, so i dont know. Can someone help me?

- no restriction in google cloud
- debugging labels for the token

Answer (score 0):

i guess this error is related to insufficient scope permissions when accessing the google Calendar api. Even though your API key doesn't have restrictions, the issue might be with the scope permissions granted to your token.

ensure that when you authenticate and obtain the token, you're requesting the correct scope permissions for accessing google calendr. Are you sure that you ar requesting the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar scope or broader scopes like https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events if you need access to events as well.

Double-check your authentication flow and to ensure that you're including the necessary scope permissions when requesting the token.